# Cannot pull the project from github using IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, maven, github, intellij-idea

I'm trying to pull spring boot project from github with Intellij Idea 2018 Ultimate.

I did it this way:

1.Clicked Check out from version control in IntelliJ

2.Copied link from github

3.Finished the pull

[image]

[image]

[image]

The problem is that after the pull from git hub all my dependencies are red (On everything it says "Cannot resolve..." ).

[image]

Screen of github project structure:
[image]

My friend pulled the project the same way like me and he does not have this kind of problem.

Could anyone tell me what may cause this behaviour?

Comment: Can you determine if the `org.springframework` package is in the source code you just pulled?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the imports didn't recognize the maven dependencies.

Right click on the pom.xml > Maven > Reimport, and that should fix the error.

Comment: It's not so much that it doesn't recognise the dependencies, but the dependencies won't get resolved until you import them explicitly or turn on autoimport for the project.

Answer (score 0):

In the first image, you can check the `Import Maven projects automatically`,
the project is automatically initialized when the pull is complete